# ViewModel for fragment in ViewPager2 throws exception

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, android-viewpager2

Retrieving ViewModel in onCreate throws exception when the fragment is being recreated by viewpager

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        model = ViewModelProvider(this)[DrawCanvasViewModel::class.java]
    }
```

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SavedStateProvider with the given key is already registered
        at androidx.savedstate.SavedStateRegistry.registerSavedStateProvider(SavedStateRegistry.java:111)
        at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandleController.attachToLifecycle(SavedStateHandleController.java:50)
        at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandleController.create(SavedStateHandleController.java:70)
        at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.java:109)
```

Comment: What version of Fragments are you using? Are you using the latest `1.2.2`?

Comment: I think you're trying to open same fragment twice via navigation, verify your implementation or try to add delay before opening the screen for testing purpose

Comment: @ianhanniballake yes, it's version 1.2.2

Comment: @HarshJatinder FragmentStateAdapter manages the fragment